# SSRS grouping on fields = a multi value parameter

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I have a SSRS Report where one of the parameters is a multi-select. I need a row group with a aggregate row that has a totals row that sums some number based on ONLY what the user selects from the drop down. For instance....if the drop down contains A = 4, B = 7, C = 1 and D = 3, let's say the user selects A and C only. The grouping only show rows containing A and C (not separating them out into groups, just returning rows ) and the total should = 5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your parameter in an expression that is can evaluate with an 'IN' clause to the multi value parameter.  Now with SSRS it handles parameters differently than SQL so I think you can get away with a little less code.  Here is an example in SQL directly that will self extract and run.

```
declare @People Table ( personID int identity, person varchar(8));

insert into @People values ('Brett'),('Sean'),('Chad'),('Michael'),('Ray'),('Erik'),('Queyn');

declare @Orders table ( OrderID int identity, PersonID int, Description varchar(32), Amount int);

insert into @Orders values (1, 'Shirt', 20),(1, 'Shoes', 50),(2, 'Shirt', 22),(2, 'Shoes', 52),(3, 'Shirt', 20),(3, 'Shoes', 50),(3, 'Hat', 20),(4, 'Shirt', 20),(5, 'Shirt', 20),(5, 'Pants', 30),
(6, 'Shirt', 20),(6, 'RunningShoes', 70),(7, 'Shirt', 22),(7, 'Shoes', 40),(7, 'Coat', 80)


declare @Ords table 
    (
        value varchar(32)
    )

--PLAY with values to see agregation works with different MULTIPLE CHOICES
-- in reality @Ords would be your parameter and the rest of the stuff if just 
-- faking a dataset.
insert into @Ords VALUES ('Shirt');
--insert into @Ords VALUES ('Shirt'),('Shoes');
--insert into @Ords VALUES ('Shirt'),('Shoes'),('Hat');

 -- simple way when you can expose dataset to join to.
Select 
    p.personID
,   p.person
,   sum(case when v.value is not null then 1 end)
,   sum(case when v.value is not null then Amount end)
from @People p
    left join @Orders o on o.PersonID = p.personID
    left join @Ords v on o.Description = v.value    
group by p.personID, p.person
order by p.personID
;

-- With SSRS you probably cannot JOIN directly to your parameter(never tried it though, maybe you can)
-- so you need to do an 'IN' expression in a CTE and then aggregate your CTE.  You can shorten this 
-- in SSRS to be in (@parameterName) instead of (Select value from @ParameterName)
With a as 
    (
    Select 
        p.person
    ,   p.personID
    ,   case when o.Description in (Select value from @Ords) then 1 end as Cnt
    ,   case when o.Description in (Select value from @Ords) then Amount end as Amount
    from @People p
        left join @Orders o on o.PersonID = p.personID
    )
Select
    personID
,   person
,   count(Cnt)
,   sum(Amount)
from a
group by personID, person
order by personID
```

Comment: Thanks djangojazz, very cool suggestion, but i perhaps should have been more clear. I was looking for a function or operation within SSRS that would accomplish that. I have an SP that runs behind the report pulling data into the report. I'm just trying to manipulate the data within the report design. I've tried using the =join function and a few other things but I just can't find a solution.

Comment: I have never done it but you could potentially group by a parameter as a 'grouping' in SSRS.  Then just do a [SUM(DataField)] and the grouping would take care of the math part automatically.  An Expression I would stay away from as you are going to have to do an evaluation and IMHO expressions are bad when aggregates.  Use them when you have to or else use sql directly, computed columns, Custom Code, or groupings.  I have a few situations where I use percentage groupings with custom expressions and I regret that choice as they are slow and need a rewrite I am too lazy to do.

Comment: If you have a procedure can you just alter the code?  The problem I have with procedures is you are taking away all the flexibility and putting it in a code.  The benefit is you can change your outcomes directly from SQL.  It is a mixed blessing depending on your situation.  I generally use views and table functions with SSRS for this reason.  The speed will probably not ever be as good as with a proc but I have more control over the presentation level.